# MySQL structure of multiple users each having multiple key pairs

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

We are looking for a sensible database structure solution to how we store key pairs for users in our database which will sit behind a website. The site will have thousands of users, against each user there is going to be at least one unique key pair. The key pairs will be VARCHAR(34) and VARCHAR(51). Users will start with one unique key pair but this could end up being thousands of unique key pairs. When the key pairs are accessed they can be done so in any order but we do want to add a field for to indicate that a key pair can be skipped.

How best do we structure the database for this?

**Solution one:** Single table for all users with User ID, Key Public, Key Private and Ignore as columns. This will end up becoming one massive table.

**Solution two:** One table per user, the table will be created and accessed dynamically. The structure will be Key Public, Key Private and Ignore as columns.

If there are any other more sane solutions then please let us know.

Comment: So you want a table with three columns, `userId`, `key1`, and `key2`?

Comment: Apologies for the lack of clarity. I have updated the question to be more concise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic creation (and access) of many identically structured tables is almost never appropriate or helpful, as it tends to bind your data to the application code built to access it because *all* queries must be dynamically created. It becomes difficult or impossible to work with database clients, perform joins, aggregation, analytics, etc without ballooning complication with dynamic SQL.  So, I would steer well clear of creating a table per user.

What you are describing instead is a very typical **one-to-many** relationship, where each user has a minimum of one key pair, and that key pair belongs exclusively to that user. What you have above as "Solution One" is therefore exactly the right approach.  It may be misleading you to think of this as a potentially massive table -- a table with a few million rows isn't even particularly large in database terms.  One reaching hundreds of millions or *billions* of rows is large and may have different considerations for scalability.  *Thousands* of rows are easily manageble.

Assuming most details about your users (which are unique) are stored in a separate `users` table, with a primary key (`userid` for example), you may store your keys in a `keypairs` table defining a `userid` column as a `FOREIGN KEY` against `users.userid`.

In its simplest form, you may not even need additional indexes, as the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint will create an index on `userid`.  But if you do expect to have thousands per user, you may eventually need to add a compound index across the pair `userid, inactive`.  At only single or a few tens of rows per `userid`, I would not expect this to be necessary.

```
CREATE TABLE keypairs (
  userid INT NOT NULL,
  public_key VARCHAR(34) NOT NULL,
  private_key VARCHAR(51) NOT NULL,
  inactive TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  -- This will ensure integrity and enforce indexing on userid
  FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES users (userid),
  -- Optionally if scalability to thousands per userid is needed
  -- Probably not needed though
  INDEX idx_userid_ignore (userid, inactive)
);
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your response. This makes perfect sense and is reassuring.